# Libreoffice Calc Finding MAX from a subset of results

Tags: indexing, max, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a Libreoffice Calc workbook for tracking writing, with 3 sheets in it. 'Time Tracking', 'Time Summary' and 'Yearly Stats'. 'Time Tracking' is where user data is entered, 'Time Summary' is a pivot table for 'Time Tracking'; and 'Yearly Stats' shows long-term progress.

Time Summary (running off some test data) looks a bit like this:

```
       |Column A (Weeks)       | ... |Column M (Total Words)
-------+-----------------------+-----+----------------------
Row 7  |02/10/17 - 08/10/17    |     |3500
Row 8  |13/11/17 - 19/11/17    |     |2300
Row 9  |30/04/18 - 06/05/18    |     |1000
Row 10 |30/10/17 - 05/11/17    |     |700
```

Yearly Stats looks like this:

```
       |A                   |B       |C
-------+--------------------+--------+----
Row 1  |                    |2017    |2018
Row 2  |Total Words         |6500    |1000
...
Row 7  |Max Words (Week)    |3500    |3500
```

The formula for 'Yearly Stats'.B7:C7 is currently `=MAX($'Time Summary'.$M$7:$M$10)`, but I need to modify it to filter by the year on the column heading.
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/62260/minif-and-maxif-function-in-calc/ looked to be useful, but when I tried it, the MAX from the formula was returning the MAX of ROW - being 10 - rather than ROW returning the position of the MAX value - even though it seems to work in the example file from the link.

The example formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($Sheet1.$J$2:$J$13,MAX(ROW($Sheet1.$J$2:$J$13)*($Sheet1.$A$2:$A$13=A2))-1,1),NA())
```

My formula uses `RIGHT()` to compare the last two characters of the column heading with the last two chars of the week in `$'Time Summary':$A$7:$A$10` and is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($'Time Summary'.$M$7:$M$10,MAX(ROW('Time Summary'.$M$7:$M$10)*(RIGHT($'Time Summary'.$A7:$A$10,2)=RIGHT(B1,2)))-6,1),NA())
```

I have, of course, remembered to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as the instructions say, to get the array in the formula to work.

So that's the explanation of my problem. What is it that I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bit long-winded, but I've managed to solve the problem by using the following formula:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(RIGHT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$'Time Summary'.$A7:$A$",COUNTIF($'Time Summary'.$A:$A,"<>''")+2)),2)=RIGHT(B1,2),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$'Time Summary'.$Q$",ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$'Time Summary'.$Q7:$Q$",COUNTIF($'Time Summary'.$Q:$Q,"<>''")+5))))),0))>0,MAX(IF(RIGHT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$'Time Summary'.$A$7:$A$",COUNTIF($'Time Summary'.$A:$A,"<>''")+2)),2)=RIGHT(B1,2),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Time Summary'.$Q",ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$'Time Summary'.$Q$7:$Q$",COUNTIF($'Time Summary'.$Q:$Q,"<>''")+5))))),0)),NA())
```

It is wrapped in an `IF` that replaces any 0 result with '#NA' (just for neatness of output).
Also the right half of the ranges specified make use of a calculation to figure out where the bottom row is, leaving out the total, so that's another reason it's so huge.